# videojs fails to change rtmp src

Tags: javascript, live, rtmp, video.js

I'm using [Videojs](http://www.videojs.com) as my client player and working on a way to change the live RTMP source dynamically with an end goal of detecting bandwidth and changing the source video to higher or lower bitrate.

The problem I'm having is when I try to simply change the source using examples I've found through other posts it's causing an error to be thrown inside video.js code.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gkzqw/2)...just open the debug console of your browser then refresh the page and you'll see an error when the timeout runs and it hits $vid_obj.src(...)

HTML:

```
<video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["html5", "flash"] }'> 
<source src="rtmp://217.23.11.44/live/myStream" type='rtmp/mp4'>
</video>
```

Javascript:

```
videojs("video_player").ready(function () {
    hsnPlayer = this;
    hsnPlayer.play();

    setTimeout(function () {
        var $vid_obj = _V_("video_player");

        $vid_obj.pause();
        $vid_obj.src({ type: "rtmp/mp4", src: 'rtmp://hsn.mpl.miisolutions.net/hsn-live01/mp4:420p500kB31' });
        $vid_obj.load();
        $vid_obj.play();
    }, 10000);
});
```

The error is "TypeError: this.ge is not a function"

So my question is have I made a mistake in how I'm trying to change the source or is this a bug that I should report under their git issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to something like this:

```
    if (this.techName === "Html5"){
        this.src(new_source.src);
    } else {
        this.loadTech(this.techName, {src: new_source.src});
    }
```

Also, **techName** available only in dev version of videojs (or minified by uglify/uglify2). You should replace **techName** by **xa** in minified version of videojs (available on videojs.com)